# I need an explanation of when to use class variables?

Tags: java

Suppose we have a class like:

```
public class test { 
  int a=1;
  static int b=1;

  public int getA()
  {
    return a;
  }

  public void incrementA()
  {
    a++;
  }

  public void incrementB()
  {
    b++;
  }

  public int getB()
  {
    return b;
  }
}
```

and I have a class with main method like this

```
public class testmain {
  /**
  * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    test t= new test();
    t.incrementA();

    test t1= new test();

    test t2= new test();
    t2.incrementB();    

    test t3 = new test();

    test t4= new test();
    t4.incrementB();

    System.out.println("t= "+t.getA());
    System.out.println("t1= "+t1.getA());
    System.out.println("t4= "+t4.getB());
    System.out.println("t3= "+t3.getB());
    System.out.println("t2= "+t2.getB());       
  }
}
```

I need the explanation about why `t` and `t1` have different value of `a`, and all `t2`, `t3`, `t4` have the same value of `b`. I know that I have declared `b` as static and all objects access the same address of that variable `b`. Why it is not causing any problem for a variable when each object it has its own `a`, now my question is since all the objects look to the same location in memory then why is `a` different value of each object?

Answer (score 1):

Every object has its own exemplar of a. So there are as many a's as objects

Answer (score 0):

Class (static) variable value will be accessible multiple instances of the class, In this case t...t4.

When you change 'b' using t.b (or) t4.b (or) test.b (or) using any methods of t..t4--> same 'b' value will be updated, becuase only one copy of 'b' exists across these.

Instance variable is specific to that instance. 'a' exists a copy for each instance t...t4.

Read this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)  for more details.

Comment: since for each obj a memory reservs two places one for a and one for b and all obj t...t4 have the same value of b why this is not happing with a as well? I know i have made b static but what does actually this static do into memory for variables ?